# UILabel Letters being cut off

Tags: iphone, uilabel, uifont

[image]I am trying to use a special character in the UILabel. But it is chopping off the labels. I put in a red background to show where the edge of the label is. Any reason why this may be happening? I have maskToBounds and clipToBounds set to NO;

```
CGSize lblSize = [FontHelper sizeForText:text withFont:[self getBodyFont] withWidth:kColumnWidth andNumberOfLines:1000];
            UILabel*lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 
                                                                    y + body.frame.size.height - columnHeight - kBottomMargin, 
                                                                    kColumnWidth, 
                                                                    lblSize.height)];
            lbl.clipsToBounds = NO;
            lbl.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
            lbl.text = text;
            lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
            lbl.font = [self getBodyFont];
            lbl.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            lbl.numberOfLines = 0;
            lbl.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
            lbl.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
```

Comment: My guess is kColumnWidth is wider than it needs to be. I would make this view in Interface Builder to assist you in troubleshooting the issue. Note: sometimes IB can be visually deceiving. If you don't notice the round drag points on the right edge of the label, it's likely that IB has autoresized your label to be wider than the screen. Double-check the size parameters, and try adjusting the width pixel-by-pixel to see at what point it wraps to the next word. I'd also set `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` temporarily to see what happens there.

Comment: I can't really build this in IB as there are no NIB files in the app. I believe it really has to do with the the "•" and the "SizeWithFont" method doesn't calculate it correctly. And the biggest problem is that the clipsToBounds does seem to work with this.

Comment: I meant temporarily, to see if it appears the same visually in IB as it does when you test the programmatically-created view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the solution. The client had give me the above text in a Word Doc and I had copy and pasted into the file.  The space between the dot and the text appeared to be a space but was other special character. So copy/paste flared its ugly head.

Comment: To anyone coming here (Like me...), solving a special-char case (Caused me a fail to compile problem) can be done with Editor>Show Invisibles (when editing an .m or .h file in Xcode).

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who stumbles on this question, I had the same problem and in my case there were a few tab characters in the UILabel, which caused the same effect.